# Using Cloudera Manager API to permanetly disable a service

Tags: python, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

Using the Cloudera Manager API I can easily make scripts that stop,start,restart series of services. However I want to make a script that permanently disables a service in such a way that if I have to reboot a server or the cloudera environment for any reason it doesn't start up on boot. I am not finding info about this online and would like to know if there Iis there any way to configure this through the API?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, aside from HDFS, you cannot disable a service.  If you want it disabled you have to delete it.

To delete the service use the service endpoint [/clusters/{clusterName}/services/{serviceName}](https://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/apidocs/v19/path__clusters_-clusterName-_services_-serviceName-.html#DELETE)

```
$ curl -u username:password -X DELETE \
 http://cmhost:port/api/v10/clusters/CLNAME/services/SERVICE
```